# Cocoapods warning on Xcode 9.3

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm getting a warning on Xcode 9.3 which was released today. I'm using cocoapods as a dependency manager.

> :-1: Target Pods-Project-test product Pods_Project-test cannot link
>   framework Foundation.framework

Is this related to the **New Build System** ?

Help is highly appreciated

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7251

Answer (score 1):

Relink the pod files inside your XCode project. This is work for me. Below you can see the files in my project.

[image]

Comment: How did you relink your pod files?

Comment: I did manually. 1) Find the missing frameworks in your Build <YourProjec>Build Phases>Link Binary With Libraries> and click Plus sine to search for this frameworks. After find and install all missed frameworks, delete the red files in your project and copy the new files to the same place.

Comment: @MaximoLucosi Please update your answer. By deleting the file indeed the message goes away. Thanks

Comment: Notice: This is not a solution if you use the new build system in the XCode.